# Failed to initialize Windows Azure storage emulator.Unable to start the storage emulator

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-emulator

Whyle starting cloud application (Azure storage emulator v 2.3) I got error:

**Failed to initialize Windows Azure storage emulator**

I have used [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg433005.aspx) to configure sql express for this purpose and I was able to create database - **WAStorageEmulatorDb32**. But still got above error. Any idea? Thanks.

**Edit**

Here is what I get when started storage emulator with  -inprocess option:

[image]

Comment: I have had this issue in the past and found clearing down old versions of tools and reinstalling 2.3 did the trick.  I should also note I have never configured this, it has just worked out of the box.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered similar issues when updating to v2.5. I tried everything outlined in the various blogs and technet forums with no luck but it seems like the advice given was correct, just slightly different for my case.

- **Uninstall all previous version of azure sdks**

  - ***Optional*** and probably not related to fixing my issue.  I uninstalled all azure sdks, authoring tools, azure tools for VS, azure libraries for .Net, storage emulators and compute emulators.
- **Delete WAStorageEmulatorDb files**

  - Next up was to clean up any previous WAStorageEmulator database files. For most users these appear to be kept in `c:\users\{user}\WAStorageEmulatorDb*.*`.

    - `sqllocaldb stop v11.0`
    - `sqllocaldb delete v11.0`
    - manually delete c:\users\{user}\WAStorageEmulatorDb*.*
    - `sqllocaldb create v11.0`
- At this point reinstalling Azure SDK 2.5 via Web Platform Installer failed to install with the following error.

  - `CAQuietExec:  Windows Azure Storage Emulator 3.0.0.0 command line tool
    CAQuietExec:  Error: Cannot create database.
    CAQuietExec:  Error 0xfffffff3: Command line returned an error.
    CAQuietExec:  Error 0xfffffff3: CAQuietExec Failed`
- **This is where I noticed my environment was different**. Running `sqllocaldb info` I noticed I had 4 instances, *V11.0*, two instances which hosted personal databases and a 4th one called *MSSQLLocalDB*. If you open `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB` in *Visual Studio - SQL Server Object Explorer* you should should see `WAStorageEmulatorDb`. The problem for me was that my WAStorageEmulatorDb wasn't being stored in v11.0 as it was for other people, so deleting `v11.0` didn't help.
- **Delete WAStorageEmulatorDb files again**. So now that I knew where my WAStorageEmulatorDb was, I re-ran the following

  - `sqllocaldb stop MSSQLLocalDB`
  - `sqllocaldb delete MSSQLLocalDB`
  - `sqllocaldb create MSSQLLocalDB`
- **Re-install Azure SDK 2.5** via Web Platform Installer completed successfully.
- Lastly, running `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\WAStorageEmulator.exe init` followed by `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage Emulator\WAStorageEmulator.exe start` started successfully.

  - To verify you should also have new `c:\users\{user}\WAStorageEmulatorDb34.*` files.

I hope this helps someone who comes across this in the future.

Comment: THANK YOU! I would recommend restructuring your answer a little as the real solution is the last two bold points which saved my bacon

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

Refer [Azure storage emulator failed to initialize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26857335/3975430) for the solution.

It solved my problem.

I hope this helps you.